# what is the source for the artscroll sidur?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mesorah-tradition, nusach-ashkenaz, artscroll

what is the mesorah for the artscoll ashkenaz siddur? Is this the same nusach ashkenaz that was used in previous generations?

Comment: just curious, are there different ashkenaz nusachs today?

Comment: @ray, there are certainly variances in terms of placement of commas (Retzeh in Shemoneh 'Esreh contains a prominent case), certain wording (differences in Birkath HaShanim and VeLaMalshinim are prominent), etc. I've also seen probably a dozen versions of Pitum HaKetoreth, for example.

Comment: There have always been different versions and adjustments made in every new siddur.

Comment: The forword/preface for the ArtScroll Siddur has a good discusssion on this.

Comment: The ArtScroll siddur differs slightly from the Nusach Ashkenaz siddur from http://opensiddur.org/, but that's actually to be expected, because ArtScroll uses Polish customs, while the Siddur Sefas Yisroel is Germanic.

Comment: They had a rabbi who did all the research for them, although I forget his name. A read through the ArtScroll siddur's Foward would tell you. I believe the ArtScroll Nusach Ashkenaz is more Litvish than Yekke, though.

Answer (score 3):

Nusach ashkenaz in artscroll is slightly misleading. 'Nusach ashkenaz' implies the german nusach when really it's minhag polin/lita. So the ashkenaz of artscroll is according to the litvish custom. If you find a siddur that's published in germany or hungary and says "nusach ashkenaz" it will be slightly different

Comment: The part of this that answers the question is "the ashkenaz of artscroll is according to the litvish custom". Can you [edit] in support for that claim?