# "B'rachamav yaaseh shalom" - origin?

Tags: minhag, kaddish

In the Kaddish d'Rabanan there is a change in the text of the Oseh Shalom. In addition to Kaddish Shalem/Yatom, there is an additional word ("b'rachamav") in the text. I asked someone who told me it's from Nusach Sefard, but it appears in Artscroll Ashkenaz Siddur as well.

What is the reason/origin to say this and why davke in Kaddish d'Rabanan? Is this nusach mentioned in some seforim?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37617/501 (what is the source for the artscroll sidur?)

Comment: G-d is merciful so gives us peace, rather than doing so because we have earned the right to it.

Comment: @CashCow but why only in *this* kaddish and not all of them?  What's special about kaddish d'rabbanan here?  (Ditto the other one-word insertion.)

Comment: Perhaps we seek His mercy for the merit of learning His Torah. This Kaddish is read after learning.

Comment: Background from [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30891): "The specific formulation of this prayer appears in the Siddur of Rav Amram Gaon (9th century) as following all three prayers. This formulation is founded on the verse in *Iyov* (25:2): המשל ופחד עמו עושה שלום במרומיו." Note, only the first three words are based on the verse in *Iyov*. "*Ya'aseh shalom*" is likely based on *Y'sha'ya* 27:5 (יעשה שלום לי), and "v'al kol Yisra'el" is likely based on *T'hillim* (125:5 and 128:6, שלום על ישראל). The addition of "*b'rachamav*" interrupts none of these biblical allusions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Nusach is from the Rambam [סדר תפילות כל השנה - נסח הקדיש](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01999.html#HtmpReportNum0047_L2) where he says:

> עשֶֹׁה שָׁלוֹם בִּמְרוֹמָיו הוּא **בְרַחֲמָיו יַעֲשֶׂה שָׁלוֹם** עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל אָמֵן.‏

The *Behr Siddur*, pg. 131 (Siddur Avodath Yiroel, without footnotes from Yitzchok ben Aryeh Yosef Dov, printed by **Rodelheim**, 1868) it says:

"It's from the Rambam and in all Sefradi versions, also in Nussach Roma. But the Ashkenazim do not have this version, **except in the Kaddish said by mourners during the 7 days of Shiva**.

In the *old brown* Sidur haGro (אשי ישראל p. 290) the end of Kadish DeRabonon has the nussach:

> עשֶֹׁה שָׁלוֹם בִּמְרוֹמָיו הוּא יַעֲשֶׂה **בְרַחֲמָיו שָׁלוֹם** עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל ואימרו אָמֵן.‏

No explanation given for the change from pg. 182 where he has the standard Ashkenaz version.

The Yerushalmim claim to have a Mesora that for the Kadish deRabonon one uses the Rambam's Nussach, but I have never seen this written anywhere. That may explain the ArtScrolls' version.